# Definition of singular point of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Given a divisor $D=\sum a_iV_i$ on $M$, where $V_i$ is an irreducible analytic hypersurface. Does a singular point of $D$ mean a singular point of some irreducible analytic hypersurface $V_i$?

I saw "singular point of a divisor" on Griffith and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry, p.137, Bertini's theorem's proof.

Comment: Come on, you've been here long enough to know that you need to add more context than this. Where did you see this language and what's the context in which it is being used?

Comment: @KReiser I added as you required

Comment: Typically a singular point of $D$ is any point on $V_i$, if $a_i>1$ or $a_i=1$ and it is a singular point of $V_i$ or $a_i=a_j=1, i\neq j$ and it is a point of $V_i\cap V_j$. Locally at a point $p\in M$, we can write  an effective divisor $D$ as the divisor of a holomorphic function and the divisor is singular at $p$ if this holomorphic function is.